# How to add a resource : xml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, resources

I'm currently using the following XAML code to add my xml file as a resource :

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="MyData"  Source="D:\myfile.xml" XPath="Books/Book" />
```

Now I would like to use this myfile.xml from the %appdata% folder, to get more portability. Obviously, using **Source="%appdata%\myfile.xml"** doesn't work, as it seems that "%" char is not accepted in XAML.

Thus I want to add this resource programmatically in my main window code. I've tried :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.Resources.Add("MyData", "D:\\myfile.xml");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

But then I don't have a **XPath=""** property available in the Resources.Add method, hence the application doesn't work correctly.

Is there a way to set this property ? Or am I doing it wrong ?

No google answer for this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet in the codebehind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider()
    provider.Source = new Uri(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\myfile.xml");
    provider.XPath = "Books/Book";
    this.Resources.Add("MyData", provider);
}
```

This is the correct code to add resources since

```
 this.Resources.Add("MyData", "D:\\myfile.xml");
```

will add to Recources a string with key "MyData" and value "D:\myfile.xml"

Or you can still use the XAML declaration and then in the constructor add:

```
(this.Resources["MyData"] as XmlDataProvider).Source = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\myfile.xml";
(this.Resources["MyData"] as XmlDataProvider).XPath = "Books/Book";
```

I suggest the last solution.

Comment: Thank You Mattias, it works with the 2nd solution. I just had to change : Uri booksfile_path = new Uri(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\myfile.xml");    as .Source method doesn't accept a string but a Uri instead.

Comment: One thing is that now, with this implementation, it's taking way more time to load my xml content (I display it in a listbox), like almost 5 secs. It was like 1sec before. Anything I can do to shorten this ?

Comment: I do not kkow... However, I am modifyng my post with your code for further references by other users.